# visual studio 2015 Coded UI not finding controld

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, microsoft-test-manager

I am getting a COM exception when running Coded Ui tests on windows 10. Is there a specific dependency I need to provide for windows 10 in order to run coded UI?

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The control is not available or not valid. ---> System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException: Element not available ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Operation timed out. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131505)

Comment: Did the same code run under 2013 or a different OS?

Comment: for me it works. Make sure the language where you created the test and the currently MUI match. Also different resolutions may cause issues

Comment: Cup- the code works on a Windows 7 machine

Comment: "This exception can be raised if the element was in a dialog box that was closed, or an application that was closed or terminated." so check your code if the window gets closed too soon via other exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The reference for the namespace *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools* is a little bit hidden.

You need to reference the DLL **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools**